# Where is the 'NET Framework Setup' key in my XP virtual machine?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, .net-framework

I installed a virtual machine in VirtualBox from XP_mode.exe. Extracted it and used `XP.vhd` virtual disk in VirtualBox.

Now when I open registry, there is no `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup` which is a described method by Microsoft to find version of .NET Framework for 1-4

[image]

Comment: There won't be one because XP did not come with .NET bundled.

Comment: I thought it was by default with 3.5? Ok, thank you.

Comment: 3.5 was preinstalled on Windows 7. Even Vista only came with 2.0 (and maybe 3.0?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP did not come with .NET preinstalled. You can take the lack of the key as an indicator that .NET is not installed at all on that machine.

If you want the .NET Framework, you will have to find a compatible copy of the standalone installer. Note that [the last available version for XP was 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000110/highest-net-version-supported-by-windows-xp).

See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

Note:

> In addition, the .NET Framework shipped with the following versions of Windows but not as truly integrated OS components:
>
> - Windows XP Home and Professional SP1 includes the MSI-based .NET Framework 1.0 + SP2 in the Additional Components folder on the installation CD.  It is not an OS component on this OS.
> - Windows XP Home and Professional SP2 includes the MSI-based .NET Framework 1.1 + SP1 in the Additional Components folder on the installation CD.  It is not an OS component on this OS.
> - Windows XP Home and Professional SP3 includes the MSI-based .NET Framework 1.1 + SP1 in the Additional Components folder on the installation CD.  It is not an OS component on this OS.